# radomly add strings to this code i have

Tags: vb6

text1.text = "Mayweather vs McGregor: Los Angeles Press Conference"
text2.text returns count of space.

my custom value say = "love"

now on each button click , i want to randomly add that custom string to each position the space.

so first click
text1.text = "Mayweather vs love McGregor: Los Angeles Press Conference"

second click
text1.text = "Mayweather vs McGregor: ;love Los Angeles Press Conference"

and so on depending on the code were it detects the space then add it their only once per click.

```
Code:

Dim Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(Text1.Text)
        If Mid(Text1.Text, i, 1) = " " Then Count = Count + 1
        Text2.Text = Count
    Next
```

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.  You are expected to try to solve your own problem and show the code that is not working along with a question.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small test project:

```
Option Explicit
' 1 form with:
'    2 textbox controls: name=Text1 and name=Text2
'    1 command button  : name=Command1

Private mstrText As String

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Static intCount As Integer 'declare as static to remember value of intCount on next click
  Dim intLoop As Integer
  Dim intSpace As Integer
  intCount = intCount + 1
  'find correct space
  intLoop = 0
  intSpace = 0
  Do While intLoop < intCount
    intSpace = InStr(intSpace + 1, mstrText, " ")
    intLoop = intLoop + 1
  Loop
  Text1.Text = Left$(mstrText, intSpace) & "love " & Mid$(mstrText, intSpace + 1)
  Caption = CStr(intSpace)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  mstrText = "Mayweather vs McGregor: Los Angeles Press Conference"
  Text1.Text = mstrText
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Change()
  'show number of spaces
  Dim intSpace As Integer
  intSpace = Len(Text1.Text) - Len(Replace(Text1.Text, " ", ""))
  Text2.Text = CStr(intSpace)
End Sub
```

Is this what you mean?